# Как оптимизировать скорость выполнения sql запроса

Tags: mysql, оптимизация

Есть таблица со следующей структурой:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `board` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `podcat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `file` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `translate` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `text` varchar(15000) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `person` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `region` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timeupdate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timesrok` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `activation` enum('1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `torg` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `free` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `color` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `select` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sendemail` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `type` enum('1','2') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `prosmotrov` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lat` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `lng` varchar(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=23859 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Необходимо осуществить фильтрация на основании пользовательского ввода, искать подстроку в одном из полей: *name*, *text*, *price*, и получить постраничный результат

у меня получился следующий запрос:

```
SELECT `board`.*, 
       (SELECT `translate` FROM `cities` 
        WHERE `cities`.`city_id`=`board`.`city`) AS `citytr`, 
       (SELECT `title_ru` FROM `cities` 
        WHERE `cities`.`city_id`=`board`.`city`) AS `cityname`, 
       (SELECT `name` FROM `category` WHERE `category`.`id`=`board`.`cat`) AS `namecat`, (SELECT `translate` FROM `category` 
        WHERE `category`.`id`=`board`.`cat`) AS `cattr`, 
       (SELECT `name` FROM `category` 
        WHERE `category`.`id`=`board`.`podcat`) AS `namepodcat`, 
       (SELECT `translate` FROM `category` 
        WHERE `category`.`id`=`board`.`podcat`) AS `podcattr`, 
       (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `board_favorites` 
        WHERE `board_favorites`.`id_board`=`board`.`id` 
          AND `id_user`='1' 
          OR `board_favorites`.`id_board`=`board`.`id` 
          AND `ip`='80.240.38.87') AS `fav` 
FROM `board` 
WHERE `status`='1' 
  AND `activation`='1' 
  AND MATCH (`name`, `text`, `price`) AGAINST ('*audi*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY `timeupdate` DESC, `id` DESC LIMIT 0,20
```

Данный запрос работает, но как то *медленно*, для каждой последующей запрошенной страницы, увеличивалось время получения результата запроса

Можно ли как-то и этот запрос оптимизировать? Нужно получить кол-во объявлений в каждой категории с фильтром по city, status, activation. Имеется составной индекс по этим полям.
Подумывал о создании отдельной таблицы для этого дела и по крону запускать время от времени и подсчитывать.

```
SELECT
   `category`.*,
   (SELECT
      COUNT(DISTINCT `id`) 
   FROM
      `board` 
   WHERE
      `board`.`cat`=`category`.`id` 
      AND `city`='1' 
      AND `status`='1' 
      AND `activation`='1') AS `count` 
FROM
   `category` 
WHERE
   `refid`='0' 
ORDER BY
   `realid` ASC
```

Comment: если Вы хотите получить ответ на свой вопрос то лучше его переписать: приведите структуру бд и что надо получить в итоге.

Comment: Вместо ответа ставите минусы. Ясно. Понятно.

Comment: Хочу получить цикл с данными. Сейчас так вот выглядит визуально http://joxi.ru/gmv7809ixj30J2

Comment: @Bald, я же написал, что если убираю JOIN то всё нормально. Значит проблема в нём, логично же.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41242/discussion-between-vitagame-and-bald).

Comment: В такой форме вопрос стал более понятен.

Answer (score 1):

я бы для начала попробовал переписать ваш запрос например как то так:

```
SELECT b.*
, cities.translate as citytr
, cities.title_ru as cityname
, category.name as namecat
, category.translate as cattr
, podcategory.name as namepodcat
, podcategory.translate as podcattr
, (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM board_favorites bf
    WHERE bf.id_board=b.id AND id_user='1'
      OR bf.id_board=b.id AND ip='80.240.38.87') AS fav
FROM board b
join (select id from board ORDER BY timeupdate DESC, id DESC LIMIT 0,20 ) b2 on b.id=b2.id
left join cities on b.city=cities.city_id
left join category on b.cat=category.id
left join category podcategory on b.podcat=category.id
```

из запроса убрал условия фильтрации, так как *тормоза* проявлялись при использовании *постраничного* вывода результатов запроса.

В решении проблемы *тормозов* при *постраничном* выводе помогла вот эта статья на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/217521/)

---

так же мой внутрений *перфикционист* не очень доволен вот этим *куском* запроса

```
(SELECT
   COUNT(1)
 FROM board_favorites bf
 WHERE
   bf.id_board=b.id AND id_user='1'
   OR bf.id_board=b.id AND ip='80.240.38.87') AS fav
```

но как его переписать я не знаю, да и не знаю надо ли это делать

Comment: время выполнения оставляет желать лучшего, 0.28 секунды при 23855 объявлениях.
И чем дальше проходим по страницам - тем медленней.